# SQL query to replicate INDEX/MATCH functionality of excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have two tables:

Product_Mapping :

```
Parent_SKU
Color
Child_SKU
```

-- Child_SKU is Primary Key

Product_Catalog

```
Parent_SKU
Color
UID
Date
```

-- UID is Primary Key

Now I want to add `Child_SKU` column to the `Product_Catalog` table.

(Corresponding to each `Parent_SKU` and `Color` combination, there is a `Child_SKU` in the `Product_Mapping` table)

How do I write a SQL query to do the same?

Comment: How exactly do you find the `Child_SKU` in the `Product_Mapping` table? What do you search for? It can't be just by color; you probably have another column too, don't you?

Comment: No its just the color. So consider the product is a shirt which becomes the parent. Different colors of the shirt are the child. UID is a single unit of shirt.

Comment: so if you also have trousers the same colour, then in order to correctly get the right record you'd have to look up by the parent SKU as well as the colour, surely?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. What an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `JOIN` should be what you need, using both fields `Parent_SKU` and `Color`. You want to use a `LEFT JOIN` in case there is no matching record in Product_Mapping.
Conceptually, this achieves the same functionnality as Excel VLOOKUP.

```
SELECT
    pc.Parent_SKU
    pc.Color
    pc.UID
    pc.Date
    pm.Child_SKU
FROM
    Product_Catalog pc
    LEFT JOIN Product_Mapping pm
        ON  pm.Parent_SKU = pc.Parent_SKU
        AND pm.Color      = pc.Color
```

Comment: Welcome @TanmayShrivastava, glad that it helped !